# getting error on nested element generation javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to alter the default header on a div with a js function but after the final result of my code is the text [object HTMLDivElement].
Here is my code:

```
    function Modelo1(){
        var div=document.createElement('div');
        var logo = document.createElement('img');
        logo.height=80;
        logo.width=250;
        logo.src="persona-5-listing-thumb-01-ps4-us-30jun16.png";
        var datos= document.createElement('div');
        var ruc = document.createElement('span');
        var dir = document.createElement('span');
        var tel = document.createElement('span');
        ruc.innerHTML = "RUC: ";
        dir.innerHTML = "dirección aca";
        tel.innerHTML = "Telefono: ";
        datos.appendChild(ruc);
        datos.appendChild(dir);
        datos.appendChild(tel);
        var doc=document.createElement('div');
        doc.border="2px solid "+colorBorde;
        var rD = document.createElement('span');
        rD.innerHTML="ruc";
        var tD = document.createElement('p');
        tD.innerHTML = "HEADER";
        doc.appendChild(rD);
        doc.appendChild(tD);
        div.appendChild(logo);
        div.appendChild(datos);
        div.appendChild(doc);
        document.getElementById('cabecera').innerHTML = div;
    }
```

Comment: `= div.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

`div.innerHTML = logo + datos + div;` Is the problem

1) you can not sum html elements
2) instead `+ div` is `+ doc`

```js
function Modelo1(){
        var div=document.createElement('div');
        var logo = document.createElement('img');
        logo.height=80;
        logo.width=250;
        logo.src="persona-5-listing-thumb-01-ps4-us-30jun16.png";
        var datos= document.createElement('div');
        var ruc = document.createElement('span');
        var dir = document.createElement('span');
        var tel = document.createElement('span');
        ruc.innerHTML = "RUC: ";
        dir.innerHTML = "dirección aca";
        tel.innerHTML = "Telefono: ";
        datos.appendChild(ruc);
        datos.appendChild(dir);
        datos.appendChild(tel);
        var doc=document.createElement('div');
        doc.border="2px solid black";
        var rD = document.createElement('span');
        rD.innerHTML="ruc";
        var tD = document.createElement('p');
        tD.innerHTML = "HEADER";
        doc.appendChild(rD);
        doc.appendChild(tD);
        div.appendChild(logo)
        div.appendChild(datos)
        div.appendChild(doc)
        document.getElementById('cabecera').appendChild(div);
    }
    
    Modelo1()
```

```html
<header id="cabecera"></header>
```

Comment: I actually just edited my answer changing div.innerHTML =  logo + datos + div to div.appendChild(), but the error still appears. To obtain the result I wanted, I just had to add div.innerHTML.

Comment: you just had to append the div into the `cabecera`